# Add right arrow to menu bar

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want to add css right arrow where ul has a ul child? Below is triangle right css. I want to add in my menu so that users know this menu has sub menu.

How is it possible to detect in pure css if a `li` has children of ul.children?

I want to add below triangle-right arrow to my css. Plz help.

```
#triangle-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

php code for the menu:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `category` where `parent_id` = 0');
$stmt->execute();
?>

<ul class="top-level-menu">
    <?php while($menu1 = $stmt->fetch()){ ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $menu1['category_link'] . "\n"; ?>"><?php echo $menu1['product'] . "\n"; ?></a>

            <?php   $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = ?');
                    $stmt1->execute([$menu1['id']]);
                    ?>
                    <ul class="second-level-menu">
                        <?php while($menu2 = $stmt1->fetch()){ ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $menu2['category_link'] . "\n"; ?>"><?php echo $menu2['product'] . "\n"; ?></a>
                                    <?php
                                    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = ?');
                                    $stmt2->execute([$menu2['id']]);
                                    ?>
                                <ul class="third-level-menu">
                                    <?php while($menu3 = $stmt2->fetch()){ ?>
                                   <li><a href="<?php echo $menu3['category_link'] . "\n"; ?>"><?php echo $menu3['product'] . "\n"; ?></a>
                                   </li>
                                   <?php } ?>
                                </ul>

                        </li>

                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>


        </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

css for the menu bar

```
<style>
/* Menu Styles */

.third-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -220px;
    width: 220px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.third-level-menu > li
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.second-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.second-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #999999;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu li:hover > ul
{
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;
}


/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;

    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover { color: #000000; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately css has no native 'hasParent' selector, but if you really do need 
pure-css you could try something like:

```css
li {
  position: relative;
   float: left; 
   clear: left; 
}

li > ul::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>
    lorem 
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```